# Option to auto install AWS Systems Manager(SSM agent) on the existing AWS EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

Is there a way to auto-install AWS Systems Manager on the existing AWS EC2 instances.

I see the SSM agent is pre-install on Amazon Linux, but how about the other OS like Redhat, ubuntu, centos?

Comment: If you have SSH access to those machines then run some automation script using Ansible, Chef, Fabric etc. to remotely install the SSM agent.

Answer (score 1):

> how about the other OS like Redhat, ubuntu, centos?

Ubuntu also has pre-installed SSM Agent. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-install-ssm-agent.html):

> SM Agent is **preinstalled**, by default, on the following Amazon Machine Images (AMIs):

```
Amazon Linux

Amazon Linux 2

Ubuntu Server 16.04

Ubuntu Server 18.04

Amazon ECS-Optimized
```

For the remaining AMIs, you could install the agent as described in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-manual-agent-install.html) and create a **custom AMI**. This way you do it only once, and re-use the custom AMIs.

As an alternative, a [User Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) could be used to automate the installation of the agent whenever an instance is launch.

Answer (score 0):

Work for RHEL 8.4 add:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
cd /tmp
sudo dnf install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm
sudo systemctl enable amazon-ssm-agent
sudo systemctl start amazon-ssm-agent
--//--
```